# Powershell Linux Sharepoint Management

Tags: linux, powershell, sharepoint

I installed powershell (pwsh) on Ubuntu 20.4. I am trying to manage some Sharepoint stuff. I did the following:

```
PS /home/polar> Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

And it installed. So, I thought.

I cannot access any commands, such as `Get-SPOSiteDesign`, etc.

I list the modules I have:

```
PS /home/polar> Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

From the following result, it seems the problem is that there are not any ***ExportedCommands*** from the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell package.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Directory: /home/polar/.local/share/powershell/Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Binary     16.0.2121…            Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerS… Desk      

    Directory: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Manifest   1.2.5                 Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive        Desk      {Compress-Archive, Expand-Archive}
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           Core      {Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript}
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     Core      {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-ItemProperty, Join-Path…}
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       Core      {Get-Credential, Get-ExecutionPolicy, Set-ExecutionPolicy, ConvertFrom-SecureString…}
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        Core      {Export-Alias, Get-Alias, Import-Alias, New-Alias…}
Script     1.4.7                 PackageManagement                   Desk      {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-PackageSource…}
Script     2.2.5                 PowerShellGet                       Desk      {Find-Command, Find-DSCResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCapability…}
Script     2.0.5                 PSDesiredStateConfiguration         Core      {Configuration, New-DscChecksum, Get-DscResource, Invoke-DscResource}
Script     2.1.0                 PSReadLine                          Desk      {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption…}
Binary     2.0.3                 ThreadJob                           Desk      Start-ThreadJob
```

Comment: I think by the looks of it [Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/introduction-sharepoint-online-management-shell?view=sharepoint-ps) is Windows PowerShell only. Can you use the [PnP module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)?

Comment: @Ash. Well, that is a bummer. I need to set up a Windoze VM, I guess. I was able to load the PnP.PowerShell module.

Comment: If the PnP module is lacking some functionality you need, you could report it in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pnp/powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sharepoint module is for Windows PowerShell Edition and not for PowerShell Core Edition :

```
PSEdition
---------
Desk
```

***Desk* = Windows PowerShell**

**Core = PowerShell Core**

In other terms, the Sharepoint doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: Thank you. However, I have found out that module PnP.PowerShell has all the capability of  Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell and then some, and it is available on Linux and for the most part works!

Comment: Yes, PnP.PowerShell is designed multiplatform and will work in linux box, but the Module you mentioned in your post (Microsoft.Online.SharePoint) is not, it will work only for Windows Powershell.